# Web API External Authentication doesnt provide an access token for Facebook Graph API

Tags: .net, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that allows users of a mobile app to log in using external authentication, specifically using their Facebook credentials.  The steps that are performed are below and lead to successfully creating a local account with the Web API by authenticating with Facebook.  I am now trying to obtain a list of the users' Facebook friends without having to authenticate again, but do not have a Facebook access token... even though i've already authenticated with Facebook!

1:  Ask for Web API login providers;

```
await client.GetAsync("api/account/externalLogins?returnUrl=/&generateState=true");
```

2:  Obtain the access token in the URL from the redirected page

3:  Register with the Web API using this access token;

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/RegisterExternal", registerExternalBindingModel );
```

4:  Now I have created an account with the Web API locally, I want to obtain a list of the users Facebook friends.

How can this be done?  The access token I have received was to authenticate to the Web API for [ExternalBearer] methods.  It returned a local access token and I am free to use the Web API... however I want to access Facebook without having to re-authenticate again via a FacebookClient object.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Still can't find an answer to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to also get the access token for Facebook (instead of the one you already have for the We API) you need to add this to the startup.auth.cs;

```
            var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "*",
            AppSecret = "**",
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },
        };
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Then from here, you are able to access it in the AccountController.cs ExternalLogin method.  i added this just before the Return OK() call. It takes the access token for facebook and adds it as a claim for the user identity;

```
        var currentClaims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id);
        var facebookAccessToken = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("access_token"));


        if (!currentClaims.Any())
        {
            await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, facebookAccessToken);
        }

        return Ok();
```

And then finally it is available in subsequent Controller calls as;

```
        var claimsforUser = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(id);
        var firstOrDefault = claimsforUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Contains("access_token"));
```